# How can I create a Navigation panel with sub categories inside Bigcommerce category page?

Tags: navigation, bigcommerce

Let's say I have a menu like Electronics. Electronics menu got sub menus like x1, x2 x3. I would like to place a navigation bar inside Electronics page with sub menu names as different menus.

Inside electronics menu:

Navigation panel: Mobiles | Mens grooming | Womens Grooming

Please let me know how can customize this way.

Answer (score 0):

To get a categories sub categories as links, you may use the Snippet named SubCategories.html . To call this snippet into the category page, you will need to use:

```
%%SNIPPET_SubCategories%%
```

Hope this helps.